# VBA: Having trouble counting and then printing the no. of rows- error 1004

Tags: vba

In one workbook, I have sales data. I want to count the number of rows (start from row 6 as rows 1-5 are blank) and then paste this into my other workbook. They're both already open and always will be during this process.The below code is returning error 1004

```
Sub StoreDateAndRowCount()
Dim SalesWb As Workbook, TrackerWb As Workbook
Set SalesWb = Workbooks("Trial 30.08.2021.xlsm")
Set TrackerWb = Workbooks("Tracker.xlsm")
Dim SalesWs As Worksheet, TrackerWs As Worksheet
Set SalesWs = SalesWb.Sheets("Sales Volumes")
Set TrackerWs = TrackerWb.Sheets("Tracker ET")
Dim last_row As Long
       Dim Date1 As Long
       LDate = Date
       'Below is where I'm getting the error
       'Application- defined or Object- defined error 1004 
 last_row = SalesWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
            TrackerWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = last_row
           TrackerWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = LDate    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use fully qualified references. When you call `Rows.Count` it's going to pull from `ActiveWorkSheet` which is not going to be the same as `SalesWs` and `TrackerWs`.

You might be getting that error because the workbook you are citing isn't open.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StoreDateAndRowCount()
    Dim SalesWb As Workbook
    Set SalesWb = Workbooks("Trial 30.08.2021.xlsm")
    Dim TrackerWb As Workbook
    Set TrackerWb = Workbooks("Tracker.xlsm")
    Dim SalesWs As Worksheet
    Set SalesWs = SalesWb.Sheets("Sales Volumes")
    Dim TrackerWs As Worksheet
    Set TrackerWs = TrackerWb.Sheets("Tracker ET")
    
    Dim LDate As Long
    LDate = Date
    
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = SalesWs.Cells(SalesWs.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    TrackerWs.Range("B" & TrackerWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = last_row
    TrackerWs.Range("A" & TrackerWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = LDate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much .Should I always use option explicit when dealing with this many variables? How do I know when and when not to use it (other than when it doesn't work)

Comment: [Always use `Option Explicit`](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-). You put it at the top of every module.

Comment: OK, thanks. So what exactly was going wrong with my initial code? I still don't really understand. I thought I had declared everything. Why would it use another worksheet when I'd clearly specified those two. Sorry for these questions- just very new to this.

Comment: Do you see where I called out the sheet object before `.Rows.Count` ? If you don't do that then it pulls the default, which is `ActiveWorksheet`. I explained this in my post. I'm not sure I could explain it any differently. Also, look at the name of your date variable `Dim Date1 As Long`. That's a typo, which is caught by `Option Explicit`.